# Creating dynamically DOM structure with prepend and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create dynamically (with jQuery) the following structure :

```
      <div id="mainWindow">
        <div id="webgl">
          <div id="global-ui">
            <div id="gui"></div>
            <div id="buttons-wrapper">  
            <div id="buttons">
            <button type="button" id="startButtonId" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" tabindex="13">Start</button>
            <button type="button" id="resetButtonId" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" tabindex="14">Reset</button>
            <button type="submit" id="saveButonId" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Save to file</button> 
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Here what I have done (with `popID = 'mainWindow'` and HTML code already contains "`<div id="mainWindow"></div>`") :

```
// Initialization of component objects                                               
    webGlDiv = document.createElement('div');                                            
    webGlDiv.id = 'webgl';                                                               
    $('#'+popID).prepend(webGlDiv);                                                      
    globalUiDiv = document.createElement('div');                                         
    globalUiDiv.id = 'global-ui';                                                        
    $('#'+webGlDiv.id).prepend(globalUiDiv);                                             
    guiDiv = document.createElement('div');                                              
    guiDiv.id = 'gui';                                                                   
    $('#'+globalUiDiv.id).append(guiDiv);                                                
    buttonsWrapperDiv = document.createElement('div');                                   
    buttonsWrapperDiv.id = 'buttons-wrapper';                                            
    $('#'+globalUiDiv.id).prepend(buttonsWrapperDiv);                                    
    buttonsDiv = document.createElement('div');                                          
    buttonsDiv.id = 'buttons';                                                           
    $('#'+buttonsWrapperDiv.id).prepend(buttonsDiv);                                     
    startButton.id = 'startButtonId';                                                    
    $('#'+buttonsDiv.id).prepend(startButton);                                              
    resetButton.id = 'resetButtonId';                                                    
    $('#'+buttonsDiv.id).append(resetButton);                                            
    saveButton.id = 'saveButtonId';                                                      
    $('#'+buttonsDiv.id).append(saveButton);
```

and I get the following structure with this just above :

[image: DOM dynamically created]

I have difficulties to insert ("opening" and "closing" tags) elements (like  `<div id="gui"></div>`)

I have noticed that `append()` adds ("opening" and "closing") tags whereas `prepend()` just seems to add opening tag at the start : I don't know how to handle this difference.

How can I fix it and create the desired HTML structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$('#'+globalUiDiv.id).prepend(buttonsWrapperDiv);
```

to

```
$('#'+globalUiDiv.id).append(buttonsWrapperDiv);
```

The order is wrong because you appended the `gui` first, meaning that when you `prepend`the button div, it will become the first element, which means gui is pushed to the second row.

```js
// Initialization of component objects        
  var popID = "mainWindow";

    webGlDiv = document.createElement('div');                                            
    webGlDiv.id = 'webgl';                                                               
    $('#'+popID).prepend(webGlDiv);                                                      
    globalUiDiv = document.createElement('div');                                         
    globalUiDiv.id = 'global-ui';                                                        
    $('#'+webGlDiv.id).prepend(globalUiDiv);                                             
    guiDiv = document.createElement('div');                                              
    guiDiv.id = 'gui';                                                                   
    $('#'+globalUiDiv.id).append(guiDiv);                                                
    buttonsWrapperDiv = document.createElement('div');                                   
    buttonsWrapperDiv.id = 'buttons-wrapper';                                            
    $('#'+globalUiDiv.id).append(buttonsWrapperDiv);                                    
    buttonsDiv = document.createElement('div');                                          
    buttonsDiv.id = 'buttons';                                                           
    $('#'+buttonsWrapperDiv.id).prepend(buttonsDiv);   
    
    startButton = document.createElement("button");
    startButton.id = 'startButtonId';                                                    
    $('#'+buttons.id).prepend(startButton);                               
    
    resetButton = document.createElement("button");
    resetButton.id = 'resetButtonId';                                                    
    $('#'+buttonsDiv.id).append(resetButton);                                      
    saveButton = document.createElement("button");
    saveButton.id = 'saveButtonId';                                                      
    $('#'+buttonsDiv.id).append(saveButton);
    
    console.log($('#'+popID)[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainWindow">
</div>
```

Comment: As both of our answer are same, I deleted my answer and edited your answer to print the final html and upvoted :-)

Comment: @Aruna Thanks :)

Comment: should be `$('#'+buttonsDiv.id).prepend(startButton);` instead of `$('#'+buttons.id).prepend(startButton);`   , not ??

Comment: @youpilat13 yes should be `buttonsDiv` as you haven't defined `buttons` yet. I only copied what you included. You also don't have `saveButton`, `resetButton` or `startButton` defined so I had to define them myself.

Comment: -@A. Lau Could we replace `$('#'+buttonsDiv.id).prepend(startButton);`by `$('#'+buttonsDiv.id).append(startButton);` ? from my test, this seems to do the same thing.

Comment: -@A.Lau 
 
Just a last remark : why `$('#'+buttonsDiv.id).prepend(startButton);`has a closing tag for starButton on the same line whereas this is not the case for `$('#'+webGlDiv.id).prepend(globalUiDiv);`(I mean, closing tag here for globalUiDiv is at the end of HTML structure) ??

Comment: @youpilat13 `append` and `prepend` have no difference for `startButton` because it's the first element. Append is putting the element as the LAST child of the parent element. Prepend is putting the element as the FIRST child of the parent element. As such, globalUiDiv has its closing tag at the end because you have children inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery was invented to make your life easier. But you continue to complicate it with native javascript)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var html = 
        '<div id="webgl">'+
          '<div id="global-ui">'+
            '<div id="gui"></div>'+
            '<div id="buttons-wrapper">'+
            '<div id="buttons">'+
            '<button type="button" id="startButtonId" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" tabindex="13">Start</button>'+
            '<button type="button" id="resetButtonId" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" tabindex="14">Reset</button>'+
            '<button type="submit" id="saveButonId" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Save to file</button>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
         '</div>';
    var popID = 'mainWindow';
    $('#'+popID).append(html);

});
```

Comment: I generally find long strings with mixed quotations to be way much more difficult to compile as well as fix if you run into misquotations, such as when you need to add event listeners such as `onclick` where you might need to further break up a single element with further `+` the only except is if you're using multi-line `\``

Comment: @A.Lau I can't see any problem to add onclick to any element on page)...just use $(document).on('click', '.listen-all-new-and-old-elements-on-page', function(){});
Of course for complex logick - i will use native javascript, but I've come across such situations only when I have problems with cross-browser compatibility

Comment: I agree with @Nutscracker... The simplicty of jQuery `.html()` versus what OP tries is obvious. The quote management is much easier.

Comment: Well what I mean is doing this: `"<button onclick=\"do_something(this, 'a string',"+variable+")\">click me</button>"` Just looks a hell lot messier and hard to follow than doing vanilla JS element create and attribute assignments. But the exception to this is using template literals, which makes it a hell lot easier to read.

Comment: @A.Lau of course this looks terrible. Who use onclick attribute  in 2017? If i want to pass any data to a function, I use a custom attribute. For example <button for="+variable+">click me</button> then in function I get all i want data by $(this).attr('for'); You offer sophisticated methods for solving simple and trivial problems

Comment: @Nutscracker I still dislike using `+` all over the place. especially when you end up having to break the continuous flow of a string. But at the end of the day, you're the coder, and the people you have to answer to are yourself and anyone else. Whether you think I'm right/wrong has no final impact.

Comment: @A.Lau However, your method is much harder to read and much easier to make mistakes. Try adding a more complex html and you'll be horrified. The person who asked the question - was confused even in such a small code. And if there are dozens of lines there? My method is quick, nice and easy to anderstand.

Answer (score 1):

Different than other answers here is how I do things with Jquery. First I have a function to create dom elements.

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.createAndAppend = function (type, attr, style) {
        var element = document.createElement(type);
        if (this != null)
            this.append(element);
        for (var i in attr) {
            element[i] = attr[i];
            //element.setAttribute(i, attr[i]);
        }
        for (var i in style) {
            element.style[i] = style[i];
        }
        return $(element);
    };

})(jQuery);
```

you can use it like:

```
var body = $("body");
var webgl = body.createAndAppend("div",{id:"webgl"});
var globalui = webgl.createAndAppend("div",{id:"global-ui"});
```

....

when you want to add buttons

```
var myButton = globalui.createAndAppend("button",{id:"myPrettyButton", innerHTML:"myButton", className:"myButtonClass"},{"width":"150px","height":"50px"})
```

As you can see, you can set inner html, class, id and any style you want. I like this way because I can do all the things in a single line.